# How to share a Github Workflow and not an Github Action?

Tags: github-actions

After some attempts I got the impression that I can use Github Actions only to share my custom actions, but not a whole workflow.

It is possible to share an [existing workflow](https://github.com/jQAssistant/ci-github-action/blob/master/action.yaml) with many repositories?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. The only thing that comes close to this (but maybe does not fit your particular use case) is executing a workflow from another repository by creating a `repository_dispatch` event.

Comment: I encountered the same need and ended up creating a "workflow dispatcher" script that generates slightly different workflows from a template, and copies them to their respective repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61543053/1237708 this might answer your question

Comment: Hi @ChandanGupta, can the triggered workflow in a different repository?

Comment: @Oliver yes it can be done. I did a POC few months ago and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @ChandanGupta Is the PoC public available?

Comment: @Oliver, nope it is not public available, but I can prepare you one. Let me make one and I will post it back to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to share workflow template between multiple github actions workflows.
However, it is only possible when you are collaborating through github organization.

Here is the link to official article.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/sharing-workflows-with-your-organization

In above case you need to have .github repo at organizational level with public visibility. But there is a another way as well where you can share your workflow with private accessibility. 
 
https://medium.com/@er.singh.nitin/how-to-share-the-github-actions-workflow-in-an-organization-privately-c3bb3e0deb3