# Trigger workflow from external repo

Tags: github-actions

I can trigger a workflow based on a push to my repo with

```
on:
  push
```

Is it possible to trigger a workflow when there is a push to another public repo that I don't have push access to, such as [phpmyadmin](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, you can't programmatically subscribe one repo to another repo's events.

However what you could do is run a [scheduled job](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule) (once per day, or more frequently if you need) to check for any updates. You could store the last known SHA in your repo, then update it via a PR or direct commit when the action detects an update.

This is similar to what tools like https://dependabot.com/ do.

Comment: I ended up using yours and @chandan-gupta solutions, by doing a repository dispatch with a personal access token if the SHA changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Repository_dispatch" trigger to trigger any workflow. The link below can be helpful to use

```
 on:
        repository_dispatch:
            types: [start-example-workflow]
```

With that payload, you can POST the request to https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/dispatches to trigger workflows

```
Accept:  application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{personal_access_token}}

{
    "event_type": "my_event_type",
    "client_payload": {
        "example-key": "example-value"
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not helpful if you don't have access to both repositories, but since I haven't found any other solution I post it anyway.

The solution can happen on push or any other event and it's using this [dispatch github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dispatch-action):

```
name: Trigger PR in PMS on release
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    name: Dispatch an update
    steps:
      - uses: mvasigh/dispatch-action@main
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          repo: from-repository
          event_type: update_event
```

then listen to the event_type from the subscribed repository:

```
name: Update event
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [update_event]

jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - run: yarn
      ...
```